# How to Authenticate to .NET Core 2.1 API using Azure AD Access Token

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Core 2.1 Web MVC API app running that is using Azure AD to authenticate. Works great, I can log in using a Azure AD account with no issues. I have another .NET application that I want to be able to make API calls to this app. I have a working class, using [Oauth2 Client Credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to AD I get a Access Token. I have tried passing the Access Token via Postman several different ways with no luck. I tried making a class to pass it:

```
        public string GetProjects()
       {
           string token = GetToken();
           HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
           client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
           var response = client.GetAsync("https://localhost:5001/Jira/GetAllProjects").Result;
           string result = string.Empty;

           if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
           {

               result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           }
           return result;
       }
```

However it always just forwards me to the login page. Here is the Startup of the hosting API app:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace CIM
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));


            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";

                               options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });



            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing to enable me to log into the .NET API using the Access Token?

Comment: You need to configure the API to use bearer token authentication, not OpenID Connect.

Answer (score 0):

As junnas said, you need to configure the API to use bearer token authentication.

You could add this configuration for the middleware needed to `validate the tokens`:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = "resource_uri",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    ApiName = "xxxxxx"
});
```

For the code sample, you could refer to: [ASP.NET Core WebAPI secured using OAuth2 Client Credentials](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1185880/ASP-NET-Core-WebAPI-secured-using-OAuth-Client-Cre).

Comment: Having a tough time with this. I tried to follow your link (thanks by the way) and installed Identityserver4 but  I get "IApplicationBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UserIdentityServerAuthentication'. I found lots of posts of others with the issue, but the common solution seems to be to restart VS. Of course... this did not work for me. Ugh. Is this portion optional? I added Junnas's suggestions but no change, still just forwards to login page, no error, nothing. Struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `AddJwtBearer` to validate the access token in your web api :

```
 services
.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Authority"];
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
    {
        // Both App ID URI and client id are valid audiences in the access token
        ValidAudiences = new List<string>
        {
            Configuration["Authentication:AppIdUri"],
            Configuration["Authentication:ClientId"]
        }
    };
});
```

And don't forget to add:

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Another way is to use the Azure AD Web API template : New ASP.NET Core application -->Choose API template -->change authentication-->Work or School Account -->choose your tenant and the template will help config your application .